# Bash to search part of pattern in a line

Tags: grep

I need to write a simple bash script that could search for part of a given string in a line (variable).
Let's say I have two variables: VAR1="helloword" and VAR2="wellford". I need to search a pattern three characters long from VAR1 into VAR2. In this case, the script should match /ell/ and /ord/ from VAR1 in VAR2.
I am thinking about to create a loop cutting VAR1 in pieces and grep VAR2, but if you guys have a better way, I will be thankful.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the first string in 3 letter chunks and compare them to the second string.

```
for ((i=0; i<${#VAR1}-2; i++ )); do
  echo $VAR2 | grep -o "${VAR1:$i:3}"
done
```